# how to edit css of children tablepagination material ui component

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am using tablepagination that is inside a modal and because of that the Select component with menuItem components is behind the modal and i cannot see it. All i have to do is apply a higher zIndex to select component, i guess, but i don't know how. The best i did so far is change the color to green.

```
const styles = {
    selectRoot: {
        zIndex: 1600,
        background: '#00ff00'
    }
}
```

---

```
<TableFooter>
    <TableRow>
        <TablePagination
            classes={{selectRoot: classes.selectRoot}}
            count={dataCount}
            rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
            page={page}
            onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
            onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
            labelDisplayedRows={({ from, to, count }) => `${from} - ${to} / ${count}`}
            labelRowsPerPage={<IntlMessages id="datatable.labelRowsPerPage" />}
        />
    </TableRow>
</TableFooter>
```

[image]

Someone could help?

Comment: A CodeSandbox that reproduces this would be helpful. It would make it much easier/quicker to try out and verify potential solutions.

Comment: Here's a sandbox where I tried to reproduce your problem, but it works fine: https://codesandbox.io/s/y0r0vvrp7v.

Comment: Are you using Dialog for the Modal or are you using Modal directly?

Answer (score 0):

It is a material UI select backdrop. You have to make use of the `SelectProps` in TablePagination props. Below is an example.

```
<TableFooter>
<TableRow>
    <TablePagination
        count={dataCount}
        rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
        page={page}
        onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
        onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
        labelDisplayedRows={({ from, to, count }) => `${from} - ${to} / ${count}`}
        labelRowsPerPage={<IntlMessages id="datatable.labelRowsPerPage" />}
        SelectProps ={{
          MenuProps: {
            style: {zIndex: 1600}
          }
        }}
    />
</TableRow>
```